# Grep Zip files in windows - Have a process that works, but could this be faster?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

Have seen posts for zipgrep for Linux..

For example - [grep -f on files in a zipped folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015866/grep-f-on-files-in-a-zipped-folder)

rem zipgrep -s "pattern" TestZipFolder.zip
rem zipgrep [egrep_options] pattern file[.zip] [file(s) ...] [-x xfile(s) ...]

Using Google, did find: http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipgrep.html and looking in their archives don't see zipgrep in there.  It also seems the Info-Zip binaries/code has not been updated in quite a while.  I suppose I could grab some of their source and compile..

Also, looked on the Cygwin site and see they are also toying with this as well..

Here is what I am using today..  Just wondering if I could make this faster?

```
D:\WORK\Scripts\unzip -c D:\Logs\ArchiveTemp\%computername%-04-07-2014-??-00-00-compressed.zip server.log.* | D:\WORK\Scripts\grep -i ">somestring<" >> somestring.txt
```

Couple issues with the code I have posted:
* Does not show which log file the string is in
* Does not show which zip file the string is in

While the zip file I posted works, it has a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: Have to ask - Why the downvote?  No feedback?  No insight?  I may not have followed protocol?  Hate to ask - but why?

Comment: There seems to be a downvoting troll who is scanning cygwin related issues and downvoting them arbitrarily. I have counted 8 of these this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Not much headroom for optimization, but it is worth noting that different implementations of unzip vary in performance. For speed on Windows, decompress the zip file using 7-zip, or the cygwin unzipping utlity. (Obtain via setup -nqP unzip, or the setup utility).

After unzipping, fgrep the directory structure recursively using grep -r.

In summary:

```
1) copy the zip file to fooCopy.zip
2) unzip fooCopy.zip
3) fgrep -r "regular expression" fooCopy
```

Rationale, because the file is compressed, you will have to incrementally uncompress the pieces to grep them anyway. Doing it as one batch job is faster, and clearer for someone else to understand.

Comment: Some helpful insights..  However, I have pretty much stuck with what I have already used.  I know that my question really is in the category of "Blue sky" but I still think it can be improved upon.